# Short-circuiting futures in clojure

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, future, promise

I've got two futures that resolve to booleans.  I basically want to do something like

```
(if (or @future1 @future2) 
  ...)
```

but, with the optimization that whichever one finishes first, if it's true, then I don't wait for the remaining future to finish; just go.  Of course if the value is false, then wait for the remaining future to finish.  Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: Dax, do futures "return" values? No, because futures are not functions. Futures (aka deferreds or promises) are *resolved* with values, which is conceptually very different from functions returning a value. Get your mind round the difference and your problem should become much clearer.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Yes I understand this.  Though given the lack of answers on this question, I wonder if the answer is really so clear.  Do you have something in mind?  I have some ideas, but most are quite convoluted and I was hoping for a simple answer to what seems a simple problem.  I updated the question with more precise wording.

Comment: Dax, whereas I understand futures in general terms, I don't know this particular language. I think that @AlexTaggart's answer is close to what you want but you need to obtain the two promises (presumably by function calls) rather than generating them inside `foo`.

Comment: If you can read javascript, then I can show you in principle how to do this. You would need to translate back into clojure.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case, you can give the same promise to the two deliverers. E.g.:

```
(defn foo []
  (let [p (promise)]
    (future
      (Thread/sleep (rand-int 1000))
      (deliver p :a))
    (future 
      (Thread/sleep (rand-int 1000))
      (deliver p :b))
    @p))
```

Calling `(foo)` will randomly yield `:a` or `:b` as soon as the first `deliver` occurs; the other `deliver` will be a no-op.

To your specific case, you're requiring two booleans be returned.  The only thing I can think of (and it's a bit messy) would be to use a third promise shared between the deliverers:

```
(defn foo []
  (let [a (promise)
        b (promise)
        link (promise)]
    (future
      (Thread/sleep (rand-int 5000))
      (let [res (rand-nth [true false])]
        (deliver link res)
        (deliver a res)))
    (future
      (Thread/sleep (rand-int 5000))
      (let [res (rand-nth [true false])]
        (deliver link res)
        (deliver b res)))
    {:or (or @link @a @b)  
     :a? (realized? a) 
     :b? (realized? b)
     :link @link
     :a @a 
     :b @b}))
```

- If `a` delivers `true` first, the `or` completes immediately.
- If `a` delivers `false` first, the `@a` returns immediately, then blocks on `@b`.
- If `b` delivers `true` first, the `or` completes immediately.
- If `a` delivers `false` first, it blocks on `@a`.

Repeatedly invoke `(foo)` and you should see expected results, specifically, when `:or` is `true`, then sometimes `:a?` or `:b?` will be `false`, but both will always be `true` if `:or` is `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I don't think either will work in my situation--I don't have access to the code that calls `deliver`.  I updated the question to make that more evident.

Comment: The common case with futures is you want the data from all of them, but can do the work in parallel.  Short-circuiting deviates from that.  I'm inclined to say just use `or`. The shortest execution will be when the first future yields `true` before the second future completes, the longest execution will be when the first future yields `false`, and the second takes more time to complete.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible with `core.async`, as described in my answer to the new [with Clojure threading long running processes and comparing their returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621344/with-clojure-threading-long-running-processes-and-comparing-their-returns) question. That answer defines `thread-and`; this question calls for `thread-or`:

```
(defn thread-or
  "Call each of the fs on a separate thread. Return logical
  disjunction of the results. Short-circuit (and cancel the calls to
  remaining fs) on first truthy value returned."
  [& fs]
  (let [futs-and-cs
        (doall (for [f fs]
                 (let [c (chan)]
                   [(future (>!! c (f))) c])))]
    (loop [futs-and-cs futs-and-cs]
      (let [[result c] (alts!! (map peek futs-and-cs))]
        (if result
          (do (doseq [fut (map first futs-and-cs)]
                (future-cancel fut))
              result)
          (let [new-futs-and-cs (remove #(identical? (peek %) c)
                                        futs-and-cs)]
            (if (next new-futs-and-cs)
              (recur new-futs-and-cs)
              (<!! (peek (first new-futs-and-cs))))))))))
```

Test with (constantly false) and (constantly true):

```
(thread-or (constantly true) (constantly true))
;;= true

(thread-or (constantly true) (constantly false))
;;= true

(thread-or (constantly false) (constantly false))
;;= false
```

Also note that short-circuiting does indeed work:

```
;; prints :foo before returning true
(thread-or #(do (Thread/sleep 3000) true)
           #(do (Thread/sleep 1000) (println :foo)))

;; does not print :foo
(thread-or #(do (Thread/sleep 3000) true)
           #(do (Thread/sleep 7000) (println :foo)))
```

Comment: Any chance this works with core.match, such that the predicate of the first matched set of results is then executed?

Comment: You can certainly use core.match with values returned from channels, they're just regular Clojure values after all. In a `thread-or` variant short-circuiting on the first truthy value you could simply return this value and then use core.match on it. If you'd like to do a `thread-and` and then in the end use core.match on whatever was the first value to be computed, you'd have to store the first returned value in a loop local (add it as the second loop local -- `res1`, say -- with initial value `nil`, then `(recur ... (if (nil? res1) result res1))`, with `...` as before).

Comment: Of course then you'd have to return that from `thread-and` in the truthy case. (Unless you want to wire your matching into `thread-and`; or you could rewrite it so you can pass that logic in from outside as a function.)

Comment: Actually, give me a minute and I'll post `thread-or`; I was actually going to do it originally but ended up pasting in `thread-and` for some reason.

Comment: Ok, here's `thread-or`. Also available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/michalmarczyk/5988303).

Comment: Incidentally, in writing the comments above I was initially convinced that it was about the *other* question; then I noticed that I'd pasted `thread-and` here too. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: And here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/michalmarczyk/5992795) with a general `thread-or` (taking an arbitrary number of functions to call) based on promises.

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely love this question. Maybe I'm surprised that to see a novel question that is so simple. Anyways, drooling aside, I *think* I have something that would work for you.

Instead of doing:

```
(if (or @future1 @future2)
  ...)
```

Do:

```
(if (or (and (realized? future1) @future1)
        (and (realized? future2) @future2))
  ...)
```

The trick is testing whether something is realized before asking whether it is `true` or `false`.

This could be generalized to a macro like so:

```
(defmacro future-or [& futures]
  `(or ~@(for [f futures]
          `(and (realized? ~f)
                (deref ~f)))))
```

And then used like:

```
(if (future-or future1 future2)
  ...)
```

Wait a second. Maybe I'm understanding your problem incorrectly. Perhaps you want to block execution until EITHER one of the futures is done and returns `true`, in which case you do the then clause of your `if`, OR both of your futures are done and neither returns `true`, in which case you do the else clause of your `if`. That's a different story.

The most succint way I could come up with isn't exactly pretty, but it's not hideously long either:

```
(if (loop []
        (cond (or (and (realized? future1) @future1)
                  (and (realized? future2) @future2)) true
              (and (realized? future1) (realized? future2)
                   (not @future1) (not @future2)) false
              :else (recur)))
    ...)
```

Now, this uses `loop` to repeatedly loop until one of two things happen: either one of the futures is both realized and `true`, in which case, the loop returns with `true`; or all of the futures are realized and all of them `false`, in which case, the loop returns with `false`. It's important to have the `(not ...)` expressions at the end of their parent `(and ...)` expression, so that you don't get stuck checking whether any futures are `true` or `false` until they are all realized.

This new solution could be generalized as:

```
(defmacro future-or [& futures]
  `(loop []
     (cond (or ~@(for [f futures]
                   `(and (realized? ~f)
                         (deref ~f)))) true
           (and ~@(for [f futures]
                    `(realized? ~f))
                ~@(for [f futures]
                    `(not (deref ~f)))) false
           :else (recur))))
```

And used in the same way as the above `future-or` example.

Now, I know next to nothing about optimization. But as far as I can tell, this certainly isn't as efficient as it theoretically could be, because once any given future is realized, there is no real need to test its value more than once. Well, here are two solutions, which I've titled `future-some`. Since the futures being tested has to potentially change dynamically after every loop iteration, I had to make it a function. In that way, this new method is analogous to `some`, not `or`. In kind, I changed the behavior to take a collection of futures (as opposed a variable number of single arguments--another difference between `some` and `or`). One solution does no double-checking (I think):

```
(defn future-some [futures]
  (if (empty? futures)
    false
    (let [res (reduce (fn [unrealized f]
                        (if (realized? f)
                          (if @f
                            (reduced true)
                            unrealized)
                          (cons f unrealized)))
                      ()
                      futures)]
      (if (true? res)
        true
        (recur res)))))
```

There's a lot to detail here, but the gist is this: if there are no futures to test, it returns `false`, otherwise, it iterates down the list of futures, testing whether any of them are realized. If a future is realized, and also dereferences to `true`, the iteration breaks to return `true`. If a future is realized but does not dereference to `true`, then the iteration continues to the next item. If a future is unrealized, it is added a list to be used in the next recursion of `future-some`.

And the other solution is more concise, but somewhat less optimal:

```
(defn future-some [futures]
  (if (empty? futures)
    false
    (let [realized (filter realized? futures)]
      (if (some deref realized)
        true
        (recur (remove (set realized) futures))))))
```

Similar to the other one, except that it filters out the realized first, then tests, then filters again (this time inverse--to get the unrealized) if it needs to recur. This second filtering is the inefficient step.

A problem with all the solutions I propose are that future cancellations would result in errors upon dereferencing, when they should probably simply go on as though that future were false. This is solvable by placing `(not (future-cancelled? ...))` expressions inside every single `(and ...)` expression, prior to any dereferencing. Or, for the `future-some` functions, you'd have to substitue the `realized?` predicate with `(some-fn (comp not future-cancelled?) realized?)`, or `#(and (not (future-cancelled %)) (realized? %))` for the faint of heart.

Again, seriously, thank you for that question.

Comment: Just to contribute to the thought process, the question came after reading this: http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-variations-joinads.aspx.  They had to create a special compiler extension to enable it, but in the end it allows not only the above, but full pattern-matching on the async bits.  I'm thinking Clojure is the type of language which could lend itself to an extremely elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: @DaxFohl Thanks for the link. Perhaps someday, if/when I know anything about F# and/or monads, I can appreciate more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't want to poll the futures every X millis and that you cannot control the creation of the futures/threads or the fn that they are executing, the solution is just to create yet more threads, each thread waiting for a future:

```
(defn wait-for-any [& futures]
  (let [how-many-left (atom (count futures))
        p (promise)
        wait-and-notify (fn [f]
                         (fn []
                           (if @f
                             (deliver p true)
                             (when (zero? (swap! how-many-left dec))
                               (deliver p false)))))]
    (dorun (map (comp future-call wait-and-notify) futures))
    @p))

 (defn sleep-and-return [what-to-return sleep-time]
  (future
    (Thread/sleep sleep-time)
    what-to-return))


(time (println (wait-for-any
                (sleep-and-return false 1000)
                (sleep-and-return false 2000)
                (sleep-and-return false 3000)
                (sleep-and-return false 4000)
                (sleep-and-return false 5000))))

>>>false
>>>"Elapsed time: 5000.933906 msecs"

(time (println (wait-for-any
                (sleep-and-return false 1000)
                (sleep-and-return true 2900)
                (sleep-and-return true 3000)
                (sleep-and-return false 4000)
                (sleep-and-return false 5000))))
>>>true
>>>"Elapsed time: 2901.309695 msecs"
```