# with Clojure threading long running processes and comparing their returns

Tags: multithreading, clojure

I have two different function on two very large sets of data that need to be processed, in the end coming down to two Boolean values. those values need to then be anded together for the final result. my question is what is the best way to create threads so the two long functions can run at the same time. my thoughts were something like,

```
(def f (future longProcessOne(data_one)))
(def g (future longProcessTwo(data_two)))
(and @f @g)
```

but I was looking for input on a better way to go about this.

Comment: Does that approach not work?  Do you have a particular problem with it?  It seems pretty good to me :)

Comment: while it worked, it had to finish both without shorting if one failed. I was looking for a faster way of doing the same thing.

Comment: @ChadJPetersen No, it doesn't have to finish both; `and` short-circuits. It doesn't _cancel_ the one it doesn't use, but that's a separate concern (and you _could_ cancel it, if you wanted to).

Comment: Oh that makes sense, just didn't cancel it that's why the println was showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Promise-based approach at the top, core.async-based approach lower down. Both short-circuit on first falsey value.)*

---

Here's a version making use of the fact that a single promise can be delivered multiple times (although only the first delivery will succeed in setting its value; subsequent deliveries simply return `nil` with no side effects).

```
(defn thread-and
  "Computes logical conjunction of return values of fs, each of which
  is called in a future. Short-circuits (cancelling the remaining
  futures) on first falsey value."
  [& fs]
  (let [done (promise)
        ret  (atom true)
        fps  (promise)]
    (deliver fps (doall (for [f fs]
                          (let [p (promise)]
                            [(future
                               (if-not (swap! ret #(and %1 %2) (f))
                                 (deliver done true))
                               (locking fps
                                 (deliver p true)
                                 (when (every? realized? (map peek @fps))
                                   (deliver done true))))
                             p]))))
    @done
    (doseq [[fut] @fps]
      (future-cancel fut))
    @ret))
```

Some tests:

```
(thread-and (constantly true) (constantly true))
;;= true

(thread-and (constantly true) (constantly false))
;;= false

(every? false?
        (repeatedly 100000
                    #(thread-and (constantly true) (constantly false))))
;;= true

;; prints :foo, but not :bar
(thread-and #(do (Thread/sleep 1000) (println :foo))
            #(do (Thread/sleep 3000) (println :bar)))
```

---

Putting Arthur's and A. Webb's ideas together, you could use core.async to and the results together while short-circuiting on the first falsey value returned:

```
(defn thread-and
  "Call each of the fs on a separate thread. Return logical
  conjunction of the results. Short-circuit (and cancel the calls
  to remaining fs) on first falsey value returned."
  [& fs]
  (let [futs-and-cs
        (doall (for [f fs]
                 (let [c (chan)]
                   [(future (>!! c (f))) c])))]
    (loop [futs-and-cs futs-and-cs]
      (if (seq futs-and-cs)
        (let [[result c] (alts!! (map peek futs-and-cs))]
          (if result
            (recur (remove #(identical? (peek %) c)
                           futs-and-cs))
            (do (doseq [fut (map first futs-and-cs)]
                  (future-cancel fut))
                false)))
        true))))
```

Test with `(constantly false)` and `(constantly true)`:

```
(thread-and (constantly true) (constantly true))
;= true
(thread-and (constantly true) (constantly false))
;= false

;;; etc.
```

Also note that short-circuiting does indeed work:

```
;;; prints :foo before returning false
(thread-and #(do (Thread/sleep 3000) false)
            #(do (Thread/sleep 1000) (println :foo)))

;;; does not print :foo
(thread-and #(do (Thread/sleep 3000) false)
            #(do (Thread/sleep 7000) (println :foo)))
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without core.async?

Comment: @event_jr: Actually it is, just edited the answer to include a promise-based approach. Also available in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/michalmarczyk/5991353).

Comment: @event_jr: Just fixed a race condition in the new code. I have to say I much prefer to use core.async and not bake my own waiting-on-multiple-producers solutions at home... Can't wait for an actual release.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It's really useful to see exactly which concerete scenarios `core.async` makes easier.

Answer (score 5):

Your approach is fairly normal Clojure code. One other choice is to use promises or if you need more complex processing you could consider using something like [lamina](https://github.com/ztellman/lamina) or if you feel like living on the bleeding edge [you could try core.async](http://blog.drewolson.org/blog/2013/07/04/clojure-core-dot-async-and-go-a-code-comparison/):

```
(ns async-example.core
  (:require [clojure.core.async :refer :all])

(defn example []
  (let [a (chan)  ; a channel for a to report it's answer
        b (chan)  ; a channel for b to report it's answer
        output (chan)] ; a channel for the reporter to report back to the repl
    (go (<! (timeout (rand-int 1000))) ; process a
        (>! a (rand-nth [true false])))
    (go (<! (timeout (rand-int 1000))) ; process b
        (>! b (rand-nth [true false])))
    (go (>! output (and (<! a) (<! b)))) ; the reporter process
    output)) ;return the channe that the result will be sent to

async-example.core> (<!! (go (<! (example))))
false
async-example.core> (<!! (go (<! (example))))
false
async-example.core> (<!! (go (<! (example))))
true
```

Of course this is overkill for your situation, though it's tremendously fun anyway ;-)

Comment: Using `Thread/sleep` in core.async code is somewhat evil -- it's eating up the thread pool sleeping. The native core.async way to do this is with a `core.async/timeout`, which will park the block's state for the duration.

Comment: yes, that's absolutely correct, I'v changed my code to use timeout. Thanks for pointing that out